# Bootstrap theme disables the menuitems

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I just created a simple theme with bootstrap. I have downloaded and customized it.
My problem is that when I click one menuitem in the main menu, nothing happens.

What do you think, what is disabling it?

https://vizszigetelesem.hu/elerhetosegek.php

```
<div class="nav-menu singlepage-nav">
    <ul class="nav-menu-inner">
        <?php
            $get_fejlec_linkek = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT top_menu_nev, top_menu_seo FROM top_menu WHERE top_menu_place = 1 AND( menu_status = 1 AND visible = 1) ORDER BY top_menu_sorrend ASC");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($get_fejlec_linkek) > 0 )
            {
                while($fl = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_fejlec_linkek))
                {
                    echo '<li class="nav-item"><a href="'.$host.'/'.$fl['top_menu_seo'].'" class="nav-link" title="'.$fl['top_menu_nev'].'">'.$fl['top_menu_nev'].'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I view the generated code in the browser, everything is correct.

Comment: It is probably because you customized it. Maybe you are missing some classes. Try this instead:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: Thats the easyest way, to give me a link, about nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after debuging, i found that this script is making you problem. It has "handleClick" function that blocks your href tags. After i block it in browser. It works.
[image]

Comment: Yes, i find and commected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try put a '.php' in your link if it's redirect to a php file. Something like:

`echo '<li class="nav-item"><a href="'.$host.'/'.$fl['top_menu_seo'].'.php" class="nav-link" title="'.$fl['top_menu_nev'].'">'.$fl['top_menu_nev'].'</a></li>'`;

Comment: No, thats not the problem.

Comment: If all your links navegate to this same site, you don't need $host. Your links could be like href="/" or href="/rolunk". 
Also you need a index file.